# How to apply format depending on absence of a CSS class?

Tags: css

If I would like to format an element that has a given class, sometimes (very rare) I use:

```
.beigeButton[class~="enabledButton"] {

}
```

What if I want to give properties to an element only when it does NOT contain the given string?
This does not work:

```
.beigeButton[class!="enabledButton"] {

}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:not`:

```
.beigeButton:not(.enabledButton)
```

Answer (score 1):

In general you would style the basic button and overwrite the style with additional classes, somehow like this:

```
.beigeButton {
background-color: beige;
cursor: pointer;
}

.beigeButton.disabled {
background-color: grey;
cursor: not-allowed;
}

.beigeButton.enabled {
background-color: green; //or just keep the basic color
}
```

you could also define a more general 'disabled class' which can be applied to any other Element this way:

```
.disabled {
background-color: red;
pointer: not-allowed;
}
```

A button with the class 'disabled' will get a grey background, though the rule `.beigeButton.disabled` is more specific as the general `.disabled` rule.
Any other element (or if the more specific rule doesn't exist or apply) will get a red background-color.

edit:
To answer your initial question, you can style the other way round too, like [marcinjuraszek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163867/marcinjuraszek) already described:

```
.beigeButton:not(.enabled) {
background-color: grey;
cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Note: check browser compatibilty [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

Hope this helps :)